# butterknife compiler error in android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio-3.0, butterknife

**"Cause: superclass access check failed: class butterknife.compiler.ButterKnifeProcessor$RScanner (in unnamed module @0x509fdebb) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.tree to unnamed module @0x509fdebb"**

I imported a project which was built in jdk 11 enviroment on android studio. I am currently using android studio flaming with jdk 11.

when i researched about this error on internet and it gave me some solutions of making some **module-info.java** file. but i dont how to add this file on my project. also some solutions said to turn to jdk 11 which i did already. but still it didnt work out for me.

Comment: Butterknife is now deprecated. Use  view binding or data binding. It is more efficient and easy to implement. Follow this link- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It bugged my head and later I found the solution, it is in gradle use the JDK version 11 instead of 16. I was using JDK16, which causes the error. When I modified to JDK 11, it all started working fine.